# How to evaluate a resume writing service

Tags: resume, career-development

My resume doesn't seem to be getting the attention I feel it deserves, regardless of the fact that I have some fairly specialized skills that are in demand.

I've taken a couple stabs at rewriting it myself, but I'd really prefer to hire someone with a track record of increasing the impact of software development resumes. I've Googled a bit, but I really don't trust any old generic resume service, since most people involved in IT/tech hiring don't know anything about technology.

Is there a good approach for identifying when a resume writing service would be beneficial? I'm not really sure if it would help me.

Comment: I made a pretty significant edit to try to keep this on topic but still valuable for you. Feel free to [edit] and clarify further if this changed your intent too much.

Comment: Rather than go to the expense of getting a writing service (knowing that they may or may not be any good), have you asked some friends or family? I used to get my father to review my resumes, and now my friends are asking me to review theirs.

Comment: Also - bearing in mind you will not get a response 99% of the time, but that 1% is worth a shot: have you asked the companies you've applied to for feedback on your resume or what turned their decision? It takes almost no time for you to respond to a rejection email with "I would appreciate any feedback on my application and/or resume which factored into your decision".

Comment: @ With so many free online resources on how to write and effective resume, I cannot imagine why would anyone pay a professional service to do that. In my experience, everything you need to have a good resume is already out there in public.

Comment: @PagMax the problem is so many of the free resources are contradictory, locale specific, and sometimes just plain wrong...

Comment: Maybe ask for a sanitized sample of their work, including before and after examples in your industry.  You can see if they take something meaningful and make it into nonsense or if they add value.

Comment: I will point out that when I have evaluated resumes to determine who to interview, many resume services create resumes that use the exact same phrases and are easily identifiable and not in a good way. By the fourth resume you have read that is identical to others, you are no longer interested in hiring anyone who clearly used that service. Do not waste your money.

Comment: Are you sure you actually need a better resume? Or maybe a recruiter, who will help with the entire hiring process. No matter how good the resume is, it won't get attention if it's not being put in front of the right people or being sent to the most appropriate opportunities. Plus, recruiters will usually offer their own feedback on resumes, and generally they're free for the candidate versus a service which will charge you.

Answer (score 1):

To evaluate a resume writing service, contact people that provide these services and ask them how you would benefit from what they have to offer - get success rates, examples of previous work performed, and references. Find out what kind of guarantee they offer. Also research online and read any articles or comments people have posted about the services that you are considering.

To identify when a resume writing service would be beneficial, you will have to consider what these services have to offer and whether it's worthwhile for you.

For example, you specifically said that you're looking for someone with a track record of increasing the impact of software development resumes, so you ask people to show you their track record of success and then decide if this is something worth paying them to do for you.

Additional information... I don't know if it's appropriate to share off-topic information, but I'd really like to help you.

You might be better of working with head hunters who know how to promote your skills and abilities to prospective employers. This is a very common way to get jobs in software development. And the head hunters might be able to give you some good feedback on how to improve your resume, especially since they get paid when you are successful.

Also, try contacting companies that hire software developers and ask for feedback on your resume. You might be able to reach a hiring manager who is more than happy to help. Plus, you might discover new job opportunities in the process.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check out customer feedback for the resume writing company at the [Better Business Bureau](https://www.bbb.org/) (https://www.bbb.org/).
Unaddressed negative reviews would be a red flag.

Answer (score 0):

**Go to (virtual) networking events and ask recruiters their opinion, or reach out to recruiting firms directly**

Recruiters see hundreds of resumes, and they know how to place people.  They have seen a critical mass of resumes and know what good/mediocre/bad look like.  They may give you plenty of advice for free, or point you to someone they've recommended in the past with a track-record across hundreds of applicants.

Best of all, they get paid when you get placed, so they have an incentive to work with you.

Especially with specialized skills, it'll be important to find someone who knows your industry.

Answer (score -1):

I understand that the customers of the service won't reveal that they have used it, neither would the company be allowed to disclose their clients. They might also claim a success rate, but that might be dubious, as hardly anyone would reveal the change in their employment opportunities after getting the professional service.

Online reviews might be a good indicator, especially if they are numerous and detailed/specific. As indicated in comments, ask a help from a few friends too; you can work in parallel with them.

Also, consider trying more than one service, because the downside is just the price of the service, but the upside is pretty large, in case one of the professional resumes really help you out in getting a better job.

Comment: Some companies show testimonials from their clients. For example, this page has 6 customers providing testimonials and they offer a guarantee: http://www.resumewritinggroup.com/examples.html. To be transparent, I have no affiliation at all with this company, I'm just presenting it as an example of how some companies provide references that will help you decide whether or not to use the service.

Comment: But how do we know about the truthfulness of the statements by customers? They could be paid reviews..

Comment: It's better than nothing, right? You hear testimonials and decide whether or not to trust them. There is a difference between a review and a testimonial. There are consumer protection laws that protect us from false advertising and marketing. Plus, you can always use bank or credit card fraud protection if you don't get what you have paid for. End result, you have to do research to identify whether a resume writing service would be beneficial.

Comment: When I see testimonials, I think 2 things. 1. This <thing/service> is marketed towards an older crowd.  2. Something is hokey.